# Unknown SMTP host

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am running a Java web application using tomcat to send generated reports via emails to the users.
I am able to send the emails but after few hours the server stops sending emails, with the following error.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: mail.mydomain.co.uk;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: mail.mydomain.co.uk
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1970)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.turnkey.email.SendEmail.sendMail(SendEmail.java:119)
at com.turnkey.thread.CommunicationThread.run(CommunicationThread.java:399)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mail.mydomain.co.uk
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
... 8 more
```

After some time the server starts sending emails again.

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem.
And how do I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sending legit emails? You might want to contact your service provider and ensure they aren't throttling your internet connection.

Comment: I think this error does not have anything to do with the service provider.... The error is Unknown `SMTP host: mail.mydomain.co.uk`
Is there any SMTP configuration I need to change or is there any Quota Limit for sending the emails?

Comment: Well, according to you, it works for a period of time, then stops working, right? Well that will only happen if your network goes out (after a while) for some reason.

Comment: But there are other applications running to communicate over internet and those applications are working fine continuously.

Comment: Are those other services hitting the same domain (mail.mydomain.co.uk).

Comment: Yes... Could this be because I am sending email with attachment???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26680/discussion-between-perception-and-ali)

Comment: can u try doing a telnet to the server at port 25 when the mail sending fails.

Comment: I haven't tried yet... Thanks for the tip, I'll try

Comment: I didn't notice it before.... here is another error at the same time when email application stops working... `java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp.mydomain.co.uk`

Comment: Facing the same issue. @Ali did you do anything specific to fix this?

Comment: I rebuilt the server for another reason and since then Its working fine... Sorry can't help much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like a failure in your name service.  The JDK isn't able to look up the host name to find its internet address.  Since this works sometimes and not others, it looks like an intermittent failure of the name service.  The name service failure could be due to some failure in your local operating system, or it could be due to some network failure communicating with your DNS server or other name service server, or it could be a failure in that DNS server or name service server itself.  Determining the exact cause of the failure will require some debugging.  Note that the JDK caches the results of name server lookups for some time so you'll need to factor that into your debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... the application on the live server is generating the error i.e. `javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: mail.mydomain.co.uk;` 
but at the same time I am able to send the email for the same SMTP host from my local machine. Could this be what you are saying???

Comment: Yes, your live server is experiencing the problem and your local machine is not.  It's **not** a problem with the mail.mydomain.co.uk server, it's a problem with the name service.  The name service is a combination of code running on each machine and network services that it talks to.  There can be failures in any of those places that effect one machine and not another.

Comment: Facing the same issue. @Ali did you do anything specific to fix this?

Comment: I think the issue might be due to some timeout caused when resolution doesn't happen in some stipulated time. I switched to a fast connection and the problem went away and when i switched to a slow one, I could see that. Not happening everytime just like u mentioned

Answer (score 7):

Also make sure there is no space at the end of smtp hostname eg. mail.google.comSPACEHERE  . Surprisingly this happened to me and finally after removing this space there was no complain about smtp host . Email was successfully sent

Comment: Thanks... adding .trim() to my properties file reader to make sure I don't get this problem again...

Answer (score 2):

Set for host the ip address of the domain name instead of the domain name.
use nslookup mail.mydomain.co.uk on cmd to find the ip address.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Specially for AIX or Linux OS environment,
We need to add the hostname in the etc/hosts file.. to sole this.
Windows operating system , this may work on Windows system as there is no strict security check however AIX or Linux must add host name to etc/hosts file in order for ping the SMTP server.

avoid doing this may lead Unknown host issue