# javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host

Tags: java, android, email

I am developing the application which sent mail using JAVA email API.
I use the office SMTP server 
Mail is sent properly in the office network but outside the office network or another data connection mail can not be sent.

It Show the error could not connect to the SMTP host 
it says unknown SMTP host.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543527/unknown-smtp-host. I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

As you are using office mail id. Most of the time due to security reason Technical team/Network team disable the outside network. So, you are able to post your main inside the office. Please contact your network team, they will give some sort of solution for host configuration.
Most likely you have a firewall on your machine or on your network
that is preventing you from connecting.

If also not resolving, please post the screen shot of your error.

Thanks,
Rakesh